# phpmailer with mysql results

Tags: php, mysql, email, phpmailer

I'm trying to use phpmailer to send out emails to each email address found in the database, but as a unique email. For some reason, it's sending duplicate emails, and it sends it out in as many copies as my query returns rows. So, if my query returns 5 rows, each recipient will receive 5 email (total emails sent is 25). I can't use the same email for multiple recipients because the email content is personalized.

What am I doing wrong with my code? Please help...

Here's my code:

```
$customers_query = "SELECT customer_name, customer_email, customer_id FROM customers";

    $customers = mysql_query($customers_query);

    if (!$customers) {
        $message  = 'Error notice: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
        $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
    die($message);
    }

    require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
    // create an instance

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($customers)) {
        $email = $row['customer_email'];
        $name = $row['customers_name'];
        $id = $row['customer_id'];
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        // use sendmail for the mailer
        $mail->IsSendmail();
        $mail->SingleTo = true;
        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->From = "noreply@domain.com";
        $mail->FromName = "MyWebsite";
        $mail->Subject = "Welcome to MyWebsite";
        $mail->AddAddress($email);

        $mail->Body = "Dear ".$name.", welcome to MyWebsite. Your ID is: ".$id.". Enjoy your stay.";
        $mail->Send();
    }
```

So, what am missing here? Why does it send that many emails?

Comment: Are all the emails it sends exact duplicates or does it send multiple emails with different names and ids for each?

Comment: Just as a side note: mysql functions have been deprecated. Llease use mysqli or PDO instead, as these are more stable and secure!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$mail->ClearAddresses(); after $mail->Send();
```

Comment: that was one of the first things I tried earlier, but if I do that, only the first recipient receives the email, all others don't get anything...

Answer (score 0):

Try something like is below, you need to be counting your rows somehow so that it doesn't re-process them. Also, the AddAddress(); function is used to keep adding email addresses to the TO: field, so you need to call ClearAddresses(); in order to restart with a fresh set of recipients.

```
$customers_query = "SELECT customer_name, customer_email, customer_id FROM customers";

    $customers = mysql_query($customers_query);
    $count = mysql_num_rows($customers); 
    $result = mysql_fetch_array($customers);
    $i = 0;

    if (!$customers) {
        $message  = 'Error notice: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
        $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
    die($message);
    }

    require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
    // create an instance

    while ($i < $count) {
        $email = mysql_result($result,$i,"customer_email");
        $name = mysql_result($result,$i,"customers_name");
        $id = mysql_result($result,$i,"customer_id");
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        // use sendmail for the mailer
        $mail->IsSendmail();
        $mail->SingleTo = true;
        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->From = "noreply@domain.com";
        $mail->FromName = "MyWebsite";
        $mail->Subject = "Welcome to MyWebsite";
        $mail->AddAddress($email);

        $mail->Body = "Dear ".$name.", welcome to MyWebsite. Your ID is: ".$id.". Enjoy your stay.";
        $mail->Send();
        $mail->ClearAddresses();
        $i++;
    }
```

Comment: doesn't help, I still get duplicate emails. I tried removing all phpmailer code and added a simple `echo mysql_result($customers,$i,"customer_email") . ' - ' .$i;` inside the loop and I get the correct results (`first@domain.com - 1, second@domain.com - 2`), but when I send the emails, both recipients receive 2 emails which are exactly the same. If I have 3 results, 3 copies of the same email are sent. Any ideas?

Comment: Did some research for you. I edited my answer, it should now solve your problem.

Comment: Duplicates should be removed and it should send an email to each address that it finds in your database.

Comment: unfortunately, that doesn't help - it sends to the first recipient and that's it, but I added error logging and the log says no recipient address was found (for all recipients after the first one). Thanks for the effort, but I'm giving up on this - I'll just run this manually somehow...

Answer (score 0):

You can do one more thing, add one more extra field in the customer table, like is_email_sent, yes or no. Once sent email you can update specific row using primary key. so it will not send the same email to multiple time..